Facing FieldPath field names may not contain '.'. Consider using $getField or $setField. when using $cond operation in mongo
I am trying to create a query where I am filtering out the number of events each day, which is represented by totalCount. Now after that, I am again filtering the number of events based on some conditions for the same day, which will give me a count of events each day, a but with some extra filter which is represented by filteredCount.
I am getting a bool expression which I want to evaluate, but I keep getting this error.
FieldPath field names may not contain '.'. Consider using $getField or $setField.

I have been trying this for the whole day to figure out the problem.
Here's how the query looks like.

[
  {
    $match: {
      "userId" : 101
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $dateToString: {
          date: "$date",
          format: "%Y-%m-%d"
        }
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      totalCount: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      filteredCount: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
           {
            $or: [
              {
                $and : [
                   {
                     "extraData.status": 1
                   }
                 ]
              }
            ],
           $and : [
             {
                 "extraData.value": "something"
             }
             ]
          }, 1, 0]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]


This is a type of query I am creating.
Also, the bool expression I am getting from an API, so I am limited by that.
The bool expression looks like this:
{
   "$or":[
      {
         "$and":[
            {
               "userId":{
                  "$in":[
                     101
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "extraData.userName":{
                  "$in":[
                     "Someone"
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "extraData.bucket.object.name":"name",
               "extraData.bucket.object.value":{
                  "$eq":"Some value"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}

This does not represent the true data, but it exactly looks like this.
Or is there any other way around to solve the problem, and if there is one.
please let me know.
Any help would be great.
I am trying to create a filter where there are two values, one representing the overall count and another representing the filteredCount, and I am doing an aggregate pipeline.

For the $and segment, use $expr like {"$expr": {"$eq": ["$extraData.status", 1]}}. Check out this official doc for more information

I am actually limited by the bool expression due to api , I think parsing it in a certain way can cause even more problems as expression is totally unpredictable . Is there any other way around .

@ray, $expr is not required since this is already inside an aggregation expression, using $eq and $-prefix on the field name should be all that is required.

@OmKashyap That boolean expression looks like the proper form to be used directly by $match, have you considered using $facet with a match in the pipeline for that count?

I've actually found a way to do this thing . I am using two aggregate queries for this thing , firstly getting the full data aggregate query , then i am using the filtered query , then matching the projection keys and getting the percentagee .
